# Why wont this code take the database schema using flyway and migrate it to docker container database?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, flyway

I have the following code to take an existing schema "config_data" and apply it to a docker container database "db":

here is my code, it all happens inside the docker-compose.yaml file:

```
  flyway:
    image: flyway/flyway
    network_mode: bridge
    restart: always
    command: -url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3311/db -schemas=config_data -user=root -password=P@ssw0rd -connectRetries=60 migrate

    volumes:
      - ./flyway:/flyway/sql
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql
    network_mode: bridge
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=P@ssw0rd
    command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    ports:
      - 3311:3306
```

My understanding is that flyway can copy the schema of one db "config_data" and apply that to a docker container db.

When I run `docker-compose up` I log into mysql workbench with those credentials, the problem is, it's a generic db with none of the tables/schema I need to have.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Check the logs of `flyway`, however its probably that the port mapping 3311:3306 is only for those outside the connection. Within the contain it remains as `-url=jdbc:mysql://db:3306`.

Comment: @danblack fixed that part, apparently I needed to keep the `-connectRetries=60 migrate`. 3306 does not persist the schema to docker container db unfortunately.

Comment: @danblack do you know how the schema is being retrieved here a bit confused: `command: -url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3311/db -schemas=config_data -user=root -password=P@ssw0rd -connectRetries=60 migrate

    volumes:
      - ./flyway:/flyway/sql`

Comment: I assume you are going off [this example](https://github.com/flyway/flyway-docker#example-4). Note `db` is the `hostname` for the database. `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3311/db` is specifying the host and the database `db` which. Note that `config_data` schema isn't created. Did you want to set that with `MYSQL_DATABASE=config_data` (which also needs `MYSQL_USER` and `MYSQL_PASSWORD` to be specified) to create that schema? I haven't used flyaway before.

Comment: @danblack Yea based it off that. When you say to note db as the hostname, that is to say that it shouldnt have port and localhost, just the `dbc:mysql://db`? I just wanted to have everything be root, because I want to have this run in Jenkins and have a docker-container to run against in there w/o touch the public db.  Also, I update the code with just the parts in the link, and the added MYSQL_DATABASE=config_data, changed the port to 5432. When I go into mysql workbench it says `Failed to Connect to mysql:5432 with root use, lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication`

Comment: @danblack I put the port back to 3306, and now that worked in a way, there is a db called config_data but there is no tables populated in it. How can I grab the same schema of that table?

Comment: Do you have migrations scripts for Flyway to run? It won't export the scripts for you. You have to do that first.